# IF/THEN To return if Column is a PrimaryKey or Not

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

hoping you can help. We have a table called SystemTableColumns which is meant to serve a data dictionary of sorts to house all the Column information for all the tables in the database. We created a Procedure to gather all the data we required, except InPrimaryKey. This, to our knowledge, is meant to be a booleen (TRUE|FALSE) for IF the column is a Primary Key. We haven't been able to figure out the magic to do this.

We realize it would be an IF statement to look at the Contraint_Type in ALL_CONSTRAINTS to look for P. But we haven't been able to figure out how to return this without it showing duplicate rows for all the other constraints included if you return Contraint_Type.

Below is the Procedure Written:

```
CREATE TABLE SystemTableColumns(
    TableName VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    ColumnName VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    ObjectType VARCHAR2(18),
    FieldType VARCHAR2(106),
    FieldTypeLength NUMBER NOT NULL,
    InPrimaryKey VARCHAR(10),
    CreateDate DATE  NOT NULL,
    LastModifiedDate DATE NOT NULL,
    ColumnID NUMBER,
    ObjectID NUMBER  NOT NULL
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_systemtablecolumns_info IS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO SystemTableColumns
            SELECT 
            T.Table_Name TableName,
            T.Column_Name ColumnName,
            A.Object_Type ObjectType,
            T.Data_Type FieldType,
            T.Data_Length FieldTypeLength,
            C.Constraint_Type InPrimaryKey,
            A.Created CreateDate,
            A.Last_DDL_Time LastModifiedDate,
            T.Column_ID,
            A.Object_ID
        FROM All_Tab_Columns T,All_Objects A
        WHERE T.Owner = A.Owner
        AND T.Table_Name = A.Object_Name
        AND T.Table_Name = C.Table_Name
        AND C.Constraint_Type = PK_Type
        MINUS
        SELECT 
            S.TableName,
            S.ColumnName,
            S.ObjectType,
            S.FieldType,
            S.FieldTypeLength,
            S.InPrimaryKey,
            S.CreateDate,
            S.LastModifiedDate,
            S.ColumnID,
            S.ObjectID
        FROM SystemTableColumns S;
        IF PK_Type  = 'P' THEN INSERT INTO SystemTableColumns (IsPrimaryKey) VALUES ('TRUE');
            ELSE INSERT INTO SystemTableColumns (IsPrimaryKey) VALUES ('FALSE');
            END IF;
        COMMIT;
    END;



BEGIN
        -- Call the procedure
         P_systemtablecolumns_info;
END;
```

**Desired outcome:**
[image]

Comment: What DB are you using?  Are you aware of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` ?

Comment: SQL Developer...keep in mind this is an assignment and we are required to create SystemTableColumns and utilize a procedure to populate

Comment: "Keep in mind".  You never mentioned this.  The correct approach to do this actual job would be to use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.  So you are asking a general question about joins, not stored procedures or PKs or anything.  You need to provide the definitions, including relationships etc., for `All_Tab_Columns` and `All_Objects` not the destination!

Comment: You probably need to move your condition into the `select` and try using `case when PK_Type  = 'P' THEN 'true' else 'false' end` as your expression

Comment: @LoztInSpace most of the class has been 'this is not how people actually do this' I'm just trying to get through it because it's my last class till I graduate. Appreciate the help and you're right with the PK_Type = 'P'...that's what I found as well I just haven't been able to successfully get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of try to insert PK_type in the end why don't just change it to true and false when select it then insert into table you wanna store the data just like LoztInSpace mention in comment.

```
SELECT 
        T.Table_Name TableName,
        T.Column_Name ColumnName,
        A.Object_Type ObjectType,
        T.Data_Type FieldType,
        T.Data_Length FieldTypeLength,
        CASE C.Constraint_Type WHEN 'P' THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END InPrimaryKey,
        A.Created CreateDate,
        A.Last_DDL_Time LastModifiedDate,
        T.Column_ID,
        A.Object_ID
    FROM All_Tab_Columns T,All_Objects A ,ALL_CONSTRAINTS C
    WHERE T.Owner = A.Owner
    AND T.Table_Name = A.Object_Name
    AND T.Table_Name = C.Table_Name
```

then insert this table into the table you want.

Comment: I tried this exact set up and when I ran the procedure is came back the with the values unchanged and I ran into the duplication. With C/P/R/C being listed repeated because of multiple constraint types listed against the column.

Comment: Did you check the table come out with this code only also got a unchange InPirimaryKey or duplicate? If not check first then see if this table have the same problem or not.